# Why it is needed to buffer the input stream ?Why can't we do it using simply the input stream?

Tags: java, inputstream

What exactly `BufferedInputStream` is doing here.
Here I have some excerpts from the code:

```
URL url=new URL("https://services.explorecalifornia.org/rss/tours.php");
    InputStream in =url.openStream();

    BufferedInputStream buf=new BufferedInputStream(in);
```

I am struck around here.I am not getting that why it is needed to buffer the input stream . Can't we do that using the `inputStream` simply?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *what* is it exactly you want to do with the inputStream?

Comment: @GameDroids I want to read the file url and build the string from it.

Comment: The duplicate question basically answers yours as well: you don't _have_ to wrap it but using a `BufferedInputStream` that doesn't hurt either.

Comment: @Thomas can you please tell me what the BuffedredInputStream is doing here.

Comment: What the `BufferedInputStream` is doing here is, err, buffering. This is a technique to reduce system calls and therefore improve efficiency. The 'explanation' by @GameDroids is basically nonsense and should be ignored. You do not 'have to download everything first before you could access the content'.

Comment: "can you please tell me what the BuffedredInputStream is doing here." - No I can't because you didn't show how it's used. It might not be necessary here but as said it doesn't hurt either and might just be done out of habit (because in many cases using `BufferedInputStream` actually helps).